# how to make a code which save admin each time login and logout activity inside a table

Tags: logging

I want to built a small plugin that will save admin each time login and logout activity inside a table. I try many codes but unable to save the login and logout activity. please help.
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with "will save admin"?

Comment: hello fuxia, i mean when admin login the login time and date saves in a table and display all history in admin panel.

Comment: You could try the [Simple Login Log](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-login-log/) plugin (found by searching, I haven't tried it to recommend it) or look at its source to see how it works. Or there are plenty of other [audit](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/audit/) or [activity log](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/activity-log/) plugins.